# Return Type: Calling a function inside Vs outside `println()`

Tags: kotlin, lambda, anonymous-function, shorthand

I'm new to Kotlin.

I was experimenting with Anonymous functions a little bit until facing different outputs for the same concept using different approaches.

- **First:** Creating my Anonymous function:

```kotlin
var greetingFunction = { playerName: String , numBuildings: Int ->
    val currentYear = 2022
    println("Adding $numBuildings houses")
    "Welcome to SimVillage, $playerName! (Copyright $currentYear)\n"
}
```

- **Second:** Creating a function that takes another function as a parameter:

```kotlin
private fun runSimulation(playerName: String, greetingFunc: (String, Int) -> String){
    val numOfBuildings = (1..3).shuffled().last()
    println(greetingFunc(playerName, numOfBuildings))
}
```

**A- Regular call for Anonymous function:**

```kotlin
println(runSimulation("Ahmed", greetingFunction))
```

Output:

```
Adding 3 houses
Welcome to SimVillage, Ahmed! (Copyright 2022)
```

---

**B- Shorthand call for Anonymous function:**

```kotlin
println(runSimulation("Different") { playerName: String , numBuildings: Int ->
    val currentYear = 2022
    println("Adding $numBuildings houses")
    "Welcome to SimVillage, $playerName! (Copyright $currentYear)\n"
})
```

Output:

```
Adding 2 houses
Welcome to SimVillage, Different! (Copyright 2022)

kotlin.Unit
```

I tried to remove the `println()` and calling the **runSimulation** function directly and the output was:

Output:

```
Adding 2 houses
Welcome to SimVillage, Different! (Copyright 2022)
```

What I really want to know is: how in the first place did I get that "kotlin.Unit" print using the Shorthand Syntax?

Comment: Technically, this question is about ***lambdas*** not anonymous functions. Anonymous functions have a different syntax. An anonymous function looks like - `var greetingFunction = fun(playerName: String, numBuildings: Int): String { /*...*/ }`.

Comment: I think these are used interchangeably, I am reading "Kotlin Programming The big nerd guide" and the chapter title is "Anonymous Functions and Function Type". The author introduces the Anonymous Functions and then refers to them as lambda and lambda-expression. @Trevor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin will [automatically infer the type of lambda expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax). Since the last line of `greetingFunction` is a String

```kotlin
var greetingFunction = { playerName: String , numBuildings: Int ->
    val currentYear = 2022
    println("Adding $numBuildings houses")

    // the last line is a string -> Kotlin will infer that the return type is a String
    "Welcome to SimVillage, $playerName! (Copyright $currentYear)\n"
}
```

the inferred type is

```kotlin
var greetingFunction: (String, String) -> String
```

[Return types for block-body functions are *not* inferred](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#explicit-return-types).
[If a function does not return a useful value, its return type is `Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#unit-returning-functions). The function

```kotlin
private fun runSimulation(playerName: String, greetingFunc: (String, Int) -> String) {
    val numOfBuildings = (1..3).shuffled().last()
    println(greetingFunc(playerName, numOfBuildings))
}
```

will therefore return `Unit`, so

```kotlin
println(runSimulation("foo") { _, _ -> "bar" })
```

will print the *returned* value of `runSimulation()`, and `Unit.toString()` is `kotlin.Unit`

Since `runSimulation()` will also print to stdout, this is effectively the same as running

```
println(println("bar"))
```

First the 'inner' `println()` will output `bar`, and then the 'outer' `println()` will print `kotlin.Unit`.

```
bar
kotlin.Unit
```

Comment: Since runSimulation() will also print to stdout, this is effectively the same as running
println(println("bar")).
This sums it all up for me. Thank you a lot.